# inheritance of private members in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, private

Are private members inherited when inheriting the class in c#?
I have read some topic related to this, somebody telling that private members are inherited but cannot access the private members, somebody telling that it is not inherited when inheriting the class. Please explain the concept. if it is inheriting can any body give an explanation?

thanks

Comment: By definition [`private`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe(v=vs.90).aspx) means that a child cannot access it (without using reflection). That's why [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a(v=vs.90).aspx) exists.

Comment: I am not talking about the accessibility, I want to know whether the private members are inheriting or not?

Comment: Don't use inheritance; use composition instead. Then the question becomes moot.

Comment: @DavidArno while I subscribe to that approach too, every OO developer should understand how inheritance works.

Comment: @weston, fair point :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you're not concerned about the *accessibility*  you are only concerned about *private members are inherited or not*

Answer is yes, all private members are inherited but you cant access them without reflection.

```
public class Base
{
    private int value = 5;

    public int GetValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class Inherited : Base
{
    public void PrintValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetValue());
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    new Inherited().PrintValue();//prints 5
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay but could you please explain the concept with some example?

Comment: Added example, Is that suffice?

Comment: +1 This answer was batter than other answers! Good work and worth !

Comment: but in this example we are calling the base class public method?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Maybe other answerers misunderstood the question or misunderstood the *concept of inheritance*

Comment: @tester : Yeah, that's the only way the child class can access the private field of the parent class. Essentially you choose to mark that field private so that you can control access to it via a method like his GetValue() method.

Comment: @tester Of course as I said before all the members are inherited and it will be in place, but to access them you need to expose them via helper methods or properties :)

Comment: Okay  ji !!! @tester It's a good way for your task . Now you can get the private member value in child class .

Answer (score 2):

You can mark things as `protected`, in which case you can access them from derived types.

Edit: In terms of whether they inherit, then yes they do. The child class is still of the parent classes type, and thus inherits everything. The child just cannot access it directly, but if you call base class methods that use the private parent field, that would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like Sriram says, yes, private members do get inherited, but they ar enot accessible.

If they would not get inherited, protected or public properties references private members would break in inherited classes.

```
class myBase
{
  private string _myProp;
  protected string MyProp
  { 
    get 
    {
      return _myProp;
    }
    set
    {
      _myProp = value;
    }
  }
}
class myChild : myBase
{
  public myChild()
  {
    _myProp = "SomeString"; // This will fail!!!
    this.Myprop = "SomeString"; // This works
  }
}
```

Here in the child class, you cannot access _myProp directly as it is private in the base class. However, the memeber is inherited, so it is accessible through the protected property MyProp.

Answer (score 0):

Members marked as `private` can be accessed only on the type where they are defined. You cannot access them from derived types.

Members marked as `protected` can be accessed on the type where they are defined and on derived types.

Members marked as `internal` can be accessed only from the assembly where the type is defined.
You may combine the `protected` and the `internal` access modifier.

When talking about values of private members: Of course they are inherited. A derived class always also is of the type of the base class. If the base class holds a private value to store some data, the derived class will do that, too - only that you can't access that value from the derived class.

Please also read the relevant article on [Accessibility Levels in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

> A derived class has access to the public, protected, internal,
>   and protected internal members of a base class. Even though a
>   derived class inherits the private members of a base class, it
>   cannot access those members. However, all those private members are
>   still present in the derived class and can do the same work they would
>   do in the base class itself. For example, suppose that a protected
>   base class method accesses a private field. That field has to be
>   present in the derived class in order for the inherited base class
>   method to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Private members can't be inherited, only protected which are like extended private members.

Comment: What do you meant by this *Private members can't be inherited* ?

Comment: Private members are only accessible in the class they are defined, so if you inherit that class you won't have access to that member unless you declare it as protected.

Comment: Of course, you're correct. but your answer is worded wrongly. It should be *private members are not accessible though they are inherited*

Answer (score 0):

What you said about private fields being inherited is totally right.

Here what happens: A subclass will inherit the behaviour of your base class. That behaviour might need some fields to work. So, your subclass will reserve some space for them, but you will not be able to manipulate those fields, only by using methods (public and protected ones)

In other words, your sub class inherits base class fields by holding them in memory, but it cannot access them.

On low level, it is your compiler that prevents you from accessing/changing those private fields, but even using reflection you can still do so.

If you need any clarification, let me know

Comment: so Sriram Sakthivel has given an example , is it using reflection?

Comment: No It doesn't. It uses behaviour of it's base class to manipulate base class's private methods

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, but you are unable to access them directly.

When class A is derived from class B, and B has a private property then that property will be there for an instance derived of class A. You are, however unable to access it. It must be there because the behavour specified in class B depends on it.

funfact:
It is actually possible to still access the private property with a thing called reflection. But don't worry about that and you should not use reflection for this purpose unless you really need to know what is going on and what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what's been said, privates can be accessed by a subclass when inner scope is in play. For example, the following will compile:

```
class A
{
    private int _private;

    class B : A
    {
        void Foo()
        {
            this._private = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer you can not access the private variables of base class in derived class directly but yes this private objects and values are initialized in base class when overriding class object is initiated (thus base class variables are inherited) and you can access them using some property or function if base class exposes them.
To make explanation more clear,

```
    class A 
    {
        private int i;
        private int j;
        protected int k;

        public A()
        {
            i = j = k = 5;
        }
    }


    class B : A
    {
        private int i; //The same variable exist in base class but since it is private I can declare it
        private int j;
        private int k; //Here I get warning, B.k hides inherited member A.k'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.   F:\Deepak\deepak\Learning\ClientUdpSocketCommunication\ClientUdpSocketCommunication\Program.cs  210 25  ClientUdpSocketCommunication

        private int l;
        private int m;
        private int n;

        public B()
        {
            i= j = this.k = l = m = n = 7; // Here I have used this.k to tell compiler that I want to initialize value of k variable of B.k class
            base.k = 5; //I am assigning and accessing base class variable as it is protected

        }
    }
```

If an object of class B is initialized then, A.i, A.j, A.k variable will be initialized, with B.i, B.j, B.k, B.l variables and if base class exposes function or properties then I can access all the base class variables.